# LINEのカルーセルメッセージを送りたい

Tags: python, python3, heroku, flask

はじめての質問です。
趣味でpythonのline-bot-sdk(1.5.0)でLINEのMessage APIを叩いてボットを作っています。
pythonのバージョンは3.6.4です。flaskを使ってます。
Webサーバーはheroku、画像はCloudinaryを使ってます。

今、LINEのカルーセルメッセージを送りたいと思っているのですが、何度試してみても
LineBotApiError [A message (messages[0]) in the request body is invalid]
のエラーが返されるばかりで、一向に上手くいきません。
ソースコードを載せます。

```
for product in range(num):
            rarity = "★" * (int(lineup[product]["gear"]["rarity"])+1)
            dst_time = __unixtime2datetime(lineup[product]["end_time"]) - now
            dst_time = str(dst_time).split(".")[0][:-3]
            thumbnail_url = lineup[product]["gear"]["thumbnail"]
            rm_ext, _ = os.path.splitext(thumbnail_url)
            res_dic = __check_exist(rm_ext[1:])
            if res_dic is None:
                r = requests.get(url=base_url+thumbnail_url, cookies=cookie, headers=header)
                res_dic = uploader.upload(r.content, public_id=rm_ext[1:])
            url = res_dic["secure_url"]
            cc = CarouselColumn(\
                title=f"{lineup[product]['gear']['name']}({rarity}) #{lineup[product]['gear']['brand']['name']}",\
                thumbnail_image_url=url,\
                text=f"C {lineup[product]['price']}\nスキル: {lineup[product]['skill']['name']}\n確率UP: {lineup[product]['gear']['brand']['frequent_skill']['name']}\nあと: {dst_time}",\
                actions=[PostbackTemplateAction(label="注文", data=f"order_id={lineup[product]['id']}")]\
            )
            crs.append(cc)
ct = CarouselTemplate(columns=crs, image_aspect_ratio="square")
retval = TemplateSendMessage(alt_text="ラインナップはこちら！", template=ct)
```

SDKのサンプルやソースコードを何度も見ていますが、どうして上手くいかないのかサッパリ分かりません。

みなさんのご回答お待ちしてます。

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to print length of your title, text, and url.

some tips for you.
len(title) < 40
len(text) < 60
url must have https

should be able to debug.

cheers,
khan

Comment: Could you translate your answer in Japanese? (Or if you can't, I can do)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Example

Comment: title: "フロントジップベスト #タタキケン" text "確率UP: マーキング時間短縮, ギア: インク効率アップ(サブ)"